# With mathematical induction prove $1 + \cos(\phi) + \cos2(\phi) + ... + \cos n(\phi) = 1/2 + (\sin((n + 1/2)\phi))/(\sin \phi/2)$

Tags: analysis

So I have to prove that next equation is true
$$1 + \cos\phi + \cos2\phi + ... + \cos n\phi = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sin((n + \frac{1}{2})\phi)}{2\sin\frac{\phi}{2}}$$

So I proved for $n = 1$ and for $n + 1$ I got:

$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sin(n\phi)\cos(\frac{\phi}{2}) + \cos(n\phi)\sin(\frac{\phi}{2}) + 2\sin(\frac{\phi}{2})(\cos(n\phi)\cos(\phi) - \sin(n\phi)\sin(\phi))}{2\sin\frac{\phi}{2}} $$

Any help?

Comment: I got that from this one $$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{sin((n +\frac{1}{2})\phi)}{2sin(\frac{\phi}{2})} + cos(n+1)\phi$$

Comment: Yes, you were right.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You want to show $$\sin (n + \tfrac{3}{2}) \phi - \sin (n + \tfrac{1}{2}) \phi =  2 \sin \tfrac{\phi}{2} \cos (n+1)\phi.$$  Since this is just a special case of an angle addition identity, reexamine how you can use this fact to complete the induction step via a suitable rearrangement of terms.

Answer (score 2):

If using mathematical induction is not critical, there is much simpler way through complex numbers.
Observe
$$
S = 1 + \color{blue}{\cos(\phi)} + \cdots + \color{red}{\cos(n \phi)}
  = \frac{1}{2} 
  + \frac{1}{2}\left(
     \color{red}{e^{-in \phi}} + \cdots + \color{blue}{e^{-i\phi}} 
   + 1 
   + \color{blue}{e^{i\phi}} + \cdots + \color{red}{e^{in \phi}}
   \right).
$$
Using geometric series you get
$$
S = \frac{1}{2} 
  + \frac{e^{-in\phi}}{2}\,\frac{1 - e^{i\phi(2n+1)}}{1 - e^{i\phi}}
  = \frac{1}{2} 
  + \frac{e^{-i\phi(2n+1)/2} - e^{i\phi(2n+1)/2}}
         {2\left(e^{-i\phi/2} - e^{i\phi/2}\right)}
  = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sin(n\phi+\phi/2)}{2\sin(\phi/2)}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

For $n$, we use the sine addition formula. $$\sin((n+\frac12)\phi)=\sin((n-\frac12)\phi)\cos(\phi)+\sin(\phi)\cos((n-\frac12)\phi)$$
We then plug this into $\frac12+\frac{\sin((n+\frac12)\phi)}{2\sin\frac\phi2}$
This gives: $$\frac12+\frac{\sin((n-\frac12)\phi)\cos(\phi)+\sin(\phi)\cos((n-\frac12)\phi)}{2\sin\frac\phi2}.$$
Applying the substitution for $\sin(\phi)=2\sin(\frac12\phi)\cos(\frac12\phi)$ and $\cos(\phi)=1-2\sin^2(\frac12\phi)$
 gives:
$$\frac12+\frac{\sin((n-\frac12)\phi)(1-2\sin^2(\frac12\phi))+(2\sin(\frac12\phi)\cos(\frac12\phi))\cos((n-\frac12)\phi)}{2\sin\frac\phi2}.$$
Simplifying gives:
$$\frac12+\frac{\sin((n-\frac12)\phi)}{2\sin\frac\phi2}-\sin((n-\frac12))\sin(\frac12\phi)+\cos((n-\frac12))\cos(\frac12\phi)$$
Using the sum formula once again gives $$\frac12+\frac{\sin((n-\frac12)\phi)}{2\sin\frac\phi2}+\cos(n\phi).$$