# Prove this formula $1+\cos\theta+\cos2\theta+...+\cos n\theta=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sin(n+\frac{1}{2})\theta}{2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, geometric-series

This is homework but I’m really stuck.
The question is to prove a fromula which states:

$$1+\cos\theta+\cos2\theta+...+\cos n\theta=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sin(n+\frac{1}{2})\theta}{2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}$$

I want to solve it using complex numbers
So I came to this
[image]
(I missed Re in last one)
Can you guys please help me finish this ?

Comment: Multiply top and bottom with $(1-\cos\theta)+i\sin\theta$.

Comment: Or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3404544/42969 or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/17966/42969.

Comment: @MartinR thank you for your consideration. It did <3

Comment: @rtybase Thank you for your consideration,I already found an answer.but thank you for your time. I checked it .It was also helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this :

This way you can easily do to prove Lagrange’s trigonometric identity:

http://faculty.bard.edu/belk/math362/Homework1Solutions.pdf original answer

[image: click here]

Comment: $2Sin(-\frac{\theta}{2})=-2Sin(\frac{\theta}{2})$.In your answer ,seventh line , what happened to the - ?

Comment: Cause we know that $2i Sinx=e^{ix}-e^{-ix}$

Comment: @Negar have u understood it completely or still not ?

Comment: This looks like a screenshot taken from http://faculty.bard.edu/belk/math362/Homework1Solutions.pdf. Please have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/help/referencing about to reference material written by others, with proper attribution.